# Correct way to build JAR files for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I've created a [simple library](https://github.com/sharukhmohammed/forismatic) to get JSON responses and map it to Java Object.
I built a JAR using *'build with dependencies'* in IntelliJ IDEA with JDK 1.8. However, this JAR works when used with other IntelliJ IDEA projects.

However when I add in Android Studio Project, I get this `Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`

I found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2taxlb/exception_when_building_bad_class_file_magic/) that some user did the same (*built JAR with IntelliJ Idea and Imported in Android Studio*)

I think I am missing something or a way to create JAR file which is causing incompatibility to Android Studio. I'm pounding my head for hours with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio, change `File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location` to `jdk1.7.x`. For the command line, ensure `java -version` outputs `java version "1.7.x"`.

Comment: That would be forcing end user of my library to downgrade to an older version of Java. I think that's not the optimal solution.